# Developing Spotify apps on Linux

Tags: linux, spotify

I just can't figure out where Spotify stores the apps on linux. There is nothing (as far as I can see) in ~/.spotify or ~/spotify.

The docs only seems to care about Macos and windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do, more precisely? The `which` command is good if you want to find where a command is located (if it's in your PATH).

Comment: The problem was that the documentation where lacking where to store the apps you're developing. Which the `which` command wouldn't have solved :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify stores apps from the App Finder in its own encrypted internal cache.

If you want to develop your own apps, once you're flagged as a developer you should be able to create ~/Spotify and put your own apps in it. They won't appear in the sidebar - you need to manually access them by typing `spotify:app:<appname>` into the search field.